# Deriving $E=mc^2$ with calculus

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, mass-energy

I am trying to derive $E=mc^2$ by using the work energy theorem. I start with the definition of work:

$$ \Delta E = \int_{0}^{x_f} \frac{dp}{dt}{dx} = \int_{0}^{v_f} \frac{dp}{dv}\frac{dv}{dt}vdt = \int_{0}^{v_f}\frac{dp}{dv}vdv $$

by parts this gives

$$ \Delta E = \Big[pv\Big]^{v_f}_0 - \int_{0}^{v_f}pdv.$$

where $v_f$ is the finial velocity attained. I working in 1D for simplicity. Using the fact that $p= \gamma m_0v=\frac{m_0v}{\sqrt{1-v^2/c^2}}$, I have to evaluate the following:

$$ \Delta E = \gamma m_0v_f^2-\int_{0}^{v_f} \frac{m_0v}{\sqrt{1-v^2/c^2}} dv$$

I find that

$$ \Delta E = \gamma m_0v_f^2+m_0c^2\Bigg[\bigg(1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}\bigg)^{1/2}\Bigg]_0^{v_f}\\=\gamma m_0 v_f^2+m_0c^2\Bigg[\bigg(1-\frac{v_f^2}{c^2}\bigg)^{1/2}-1\Bigg] \\ =\gamma m_0 v_f^2 +\frac{m_0 c^2}{\gamma}-m_0 c^2$$

At which point I get stuck. I can't see what I have done wrong. The similar derivation that I have seen [here](http://www.emc2-explained.info/Emc2/Deriving.htm#.WcfTpsiGPIU) appears to have evaluated the integral incorrectly?

Any hints will be appreciated!

Comment: Hint: $\gamma m_0 v_f^2 +\dfrac{m_0 c^2}{\gamma}=\gamma m_0(v_f^2+c^2/\gamma^2)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have done no mistake. Proceed further. Add the rest mass energy term in the kinetic energy term i.e in LHS of your last equation and simplify to replace vf from mass variation formula,you will get the result. The sum of kinetic energy and rest mass energy gives total energy E.